# Understanding Gaia DR3 Halpha width lines

Tags: spectroscopy

Gaia provides low resolution spectra from BP/RP filters and the values of equivalents width for hydrogen spectral lines are also provided in it's stellar database. How can there be negative equivalent widths of Halpha spectral lines values as shown in the picture below? Shouldn't they all be negative or positive?

[image: pseudo- Halpha widths from Gaia]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A negative equivalent width indicates an emission line rather than an absorption line.

Many stars exhibit H$\alpha$ in emission, for various reasons.